# What kind of changes occur when a new OS for Android/iOS is launched for which we need to upgrade applications?

Tags: android, ios7

This was an interview question for an Associate Mobile Developer position that I was not able to answer properly. Can somebody please shed some light on the matter?

The whole question was presented this way:
After the launch of iOS7 a lot of applications needed to be upgraded in order to make them work with iOS7. What kind of changes occur when a new OS for Android/iOS is launched for which we need to upgrade our applications? Why can't an application running on iOS5/6 properly function on iOS7? No need for being specific about iOS7. I want a generic answer that explains the compatibility issue for past and future upgrades on any platform.

My answer was more towards the UI/UX compatibility but the interviewer was not very happy with the answer. What could I have said more?

Comment: Regarding Android: nothing, apps written for the first version should still run on that latest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the majority of the cases, most operating systems updates are designed to be backward compatible. This means that an application written and optimized to run on a specific version of an OS should run without any problems on the next version.

Backward compatibility is usually preserved for a few 'generations'. An app running on version 1.0 of an OS is very likely to run on version 2.0, probably on version 3.0 but maybe not on version 4.0 or later.

New APIs are designed to implement new technologies and old APIs are marked as obsolete. Obsolete APIs are still part of the newer OS version, but their use is discouraged for new development.

*"Why can't an application running on iOS5/6 properly function on iOS7?"* This statement is too general, and I would say that only a small percentage of application suffer from this.

There are some technological changes that might affect more than others. For example, a hardware upgrade on a device is much more drastic than an algorithm change.

And there's obviously the commercial reason, and for some brands like Apple, this might be the biggest reason to compromise backward compatibility. In Apple's case, the backward compatibility is also restricted with the App Store policies. To upload an App to the store, you need to comply with certain guidelines that implicitly force you to upgrade or rewrite some of your code, and sometimes it forces you to buy the latest development tools, which only run in the latest OS which only runs on the newest machines.